# Institution's name and individual authors at the same time in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, citing, author

Usually, when LaTeX for whatever reason can't or shouldn't handle the name of an author in my bibliography, one uses `{{}}` to fix the author to the correct input.

But, **what can I do, if the `authors`-field consists of individual persons and e.g. an institution at the same time?**

An example would be

```
@TechReport{MDS17,
    author={Schempp, Nadine and Strippel, Harald and Medizinischer Dienst des Spitzenverbandes},
    Shortauthor = {MDS},
    title={Präventionsbericht 2017},
    subtitle={Leistungen der gesetzlichen Krankenversicherung: Primärprävention und Gesundheitsförderung. Berichtsjahr 2016},
    year={2017},
    publisher={Medizinischer Dienst des Spitzenverbandes}
}
```

where I can not simply use

```
author={{Schempp, N. and Strippel, H. and Medizinischer Dienst des Spitzenverbandes}}
```

because the formatting of the names has to be different in a citation vs in the references themselves.

---

What I want to achieve is

- in citations:

  > (Schempp, Strippel and Medizinischer Dienst des Spitzenverbandes, 2017)
- in References:

  > Schempp, N. and Strippel, H. and Medizinischer Dienst des Spitzenverbandes. (2017).

So how can I tell `biblatex` that only the third "Author" (which is an institution here) should not be separated into given- and family name but kept as it is?

Comment: `author={Schempp, Nadine and Strippel, Harald and {Medizinischer Dienst des Spitzenverbandes}},`

Comment: Seems that I made a mistake while testing this. ShouId delete the question?

Comment: Do what you think makes sense. If you decide to keep the question, you should probably remove the comments about the braces not working, though.

Comment: Please do not answer your question in the question. Questions should only be answered in the answer space below.

Comment: Ok, done. I felt that I should not connote that it was me who solved the question, but in the end, I guess it is only important that the question is answered.  Thanks.

Comment: Of course you could have asked me to write an answer `;-)`, but I'm fine with you writing one as well. It is just a bad idea to answer in the question because that bypasses the voting mechanism, answer acceptance and could potentially be confusing at first (why is there an answer in the question?, why is there no real answer? is something wrong with the suggestion? etc. ...)

Comment: Yes, I see why it should not be done. :)

If you add your comment as an answer, I'll set it as the accepted answer and remove mine. :)I thought you don't want to answer "as a real answer" because the solution was so obvious, and thus you answered in the comments. :D

Comment: No, your answer is fine. I often answer in the comments when I did not have the time to double-check my suggestion with a real document or when I'm not sure I understand the question correctly. See also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3238/35864

Answer (score 1):

@moewes comment solved the question in the most obvious way. I made a mistake while testing this, so I thought it does not work (but it does!).

The solution thus is:

```
author={Schempp, Nadine and Strippel, Harald and {Medizinischer Dienst des Spitzenverbandes}}
```